# pandas dataframe return first word in string for column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['abarth 1.4 a','abarth 1 a','land rover 1.3 r','land rover 2',
                           'land rover 5 g','mazda 4.55 bl'], 
                   'series': ['a','a','r','','g', 'bl'] })
```

I would like to remove the 'series' string from the corresponding id, so the end result should be:

Final result should be `'id': ['abarth 1.4','abarth 1','land rover 1.3','land rover 2','land rover 5', 'mazda 4.55']`

Currently I am using df.apply:

```
df.id = df.apply(lambda x: x['id'].replace(x['series'], ''), axis =1)
```

But this removes all instances of the strings, even in other words, like so:
`'id': ['brth 1.4','brth 1','land ove 1.3','land rover 2','land rover 5', 'mazda 4.55']`

Should I somehow mix and match regex with the variable inside df.apply, like so?

```
df.id = df.apply(lambda x: x['id'].replace(r'\b' + x['series'], ''), axis =1)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `str.split` and `str.get` and assign using `loc` only where `df.make == ''`

```
df.loc[df.make == '', 'make'] = df.id.str.split().str.get(0)

print df

               id    make
0      abarth 1.4  abarth
1        abarth 1  abarth
2  land rover 1.3   rover
3    land rover 2   rover
4    land rover 5   rover
5      mazda 4.55   mazda
```

Answer (score 13):

It's simple. Use as follows:

```
df['make'] = df['id'].str.split(' ').str[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

IDK why but with the part below

```
df.loc[df.make == '', 'make']
```

OR

```
df.loc[df['make'] == '', 'make']
```

I get the error - **KeyError: 'make'**

So instead I did (in case someone sees the same error):

```
df['make'] = df['id']
df['make'] = df.id.str.split().str.get(0)
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a regex solution with `loc` where it extracts everything before first space:

```
df.loc[df['make']=='', 'make'] = df['id'].str.extract('(.*) ', expand=False)
```

Alternatively, use numpy's `where` which allows the if/then/else conditional logic:

```
df['make'] = np.where(df['make']=='', 
                      df['id'].str.extract('(.*) ', expand=False), 
                      df['make'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly you can just use `replace` function:

```
df.make = df.make.replace("", test.id)
```

Comment: OP requires first word of `id` column.